# Last cell is not visible in custom Android ListView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView` + (`Control for sending messages`) layout for sending messages and displaying chat. The problem is that the last cell of a `ListView` is not visible completely (it is like behind a blue control for writing and sending messages):

[image]

I have already added to my `Manifest` file this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

and this is my xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/color_custom_light_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/message_list_edittext_hint"
            android:lines="2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/clearButton"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_button_selector"
            android:contentDescription="@string/clear_button_content_description"
            android:onClick="clearLetterClicked" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/clearButton"
            android:onClick="sendClicked"
            android:text="@string/message_list_edittext_send"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, I want the last cell become visible when I scroll to the end of my `ListView` with chat messages.

Comment: Is it still invisible if you minimize the keyboard?

Comment: yes, if there are many messages it is still not completely visible when I scroll to top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your ListView **AFTER** your your footer layout.
The container is a RelativeLayout, so you can set the ListVew **ABOVE** the footer layout.
Also set its height to **FILL_PARENT**.
So, it won't be covered by it. It will stop growing before the footer starts.
Easy fix, does the tricks.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that my simple fix was helpful. You can do the very same with a custom header instead of the default title (this time, add the attribute **layout_below** your header view or layout).